# How do I display 2 sections side-by-side?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have following HTML code:

```
<section class="indent-1">
    <!-- Section 1 --> 
    <section>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some more</div>
    </section>

    <!-- Section 2 -->
    <section>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some more</div>
    </section>
</section>
```

And I'd like to display **Section 1** on the left and **Section 2** on the right instead of vertically like they normally appear. The parent section surrounding them is indented `120px`, and I'd like to preserve that.

**How do I accomplish this?** I tried `float: left` on **Section 1** and `display: inline` on the parent section, but those seemed to cause **Section 2** to "break out" of its parent section.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Float them both left with a set width on each section and you'll be OK, like so:

```
<style>
    .indent-1 {float: left;}
    .indent-1 section {width: 50%; float: left;}
</style>

<section class="indent-1">
    <!-- Section 1 --> 
    <section>
        <div>Some content 1</div>
        <div>Some more 1</div>
    </section>

    <!-- Section 2 -->
    <section>
        <div>Some content 2</div>
        <div>Some more 2</div>
    </section>
</section>
```

No need to change your markup this way.

Also here for further info on the CSS box model: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `overflow:hidden;` to the parent.

**Preview:**

[image]

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    section { border:1px solid red; padding:10px; overflow:hidden; }
    section > section { float:left; }
    .indent-1 { padding-left:120px; }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<section class="indent-1">
    <!-- Section 1 --> 
    <section>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some more</div>
    </section>

    <!-- Section 2 -->
    <section>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some more</div>
    </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have section1 and section2 in separate div's and try `float: left` on section1 div and `float: right` on section2 div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    section.left{float:left;}
</style>
<section class="indent-1">
    <!-- Section 1 --> 
    <section class="left">
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some more</div>
    </section>

    <!-- Section 2 -->
    <section>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Some more</div>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Both sections should be floated left for them to "stack up" from the left.. *afaik*